# use string in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this in my controller:

```
string PONumber = Request.QueryString["PONumber"];
return View();
```

My question is how would I use the string in my view ?

I have tried:

```
@{
 ViewBag.PONumber
}
```

but I get this error:

This operation will be resolved at runtime. Am I not doing this right ?

I have also tried:

```
<%= PONumber %>
```

and that also did not work

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You are using razor view engine or aspx?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the result from your querystring *into* the `ViewBag` before you can pull it out of the `ViewBag` in your view:

```
// Assign directly to ViewBag
ViewBag.PONumber = Request.QueryString["PONumber"];

return View();
```

In your view, don't try to print the value by writing it in a code block (`@{ }`); simply use it where you'd like:

```
<h2>The PO Number is @ViewBag.PONumber.</h2>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than it "did not work"? Have you tried debugging your view? Have you debugging your controller to make sure you even have a value for `PONumber`?

Answer (score 3):

You have a misnomer, when you have a `Controller` with:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetExample(string PONumber)
{

}
```

The `PONumber` parameter, would represent said equivalent for your *Query String*.   So you honestly wouldn't need to manually call `Request.QueryString[...]`.

So you would assign parameter, directly to your `ViewBag`.  However, you could add it directly to a model and display through your model also.

If your wanting to use a `ViewBag`, you would simply do:

```
// Front End:
@ViewBag.PONumber

// Back End:
ViewBag.PONumber = PONumber;
```

Also, make sure when you request your data that it isn't actually a `null` or `empty` value.

Answer (score 1):

```
ViewBag.PONumber = Request.QueryString["PONumber"];
return View();
```

and then in view

```
@ViewBag.PONumber
```